# resttemplate equivalent/mapping of curl -T or --upload-file option

Tags: java, spring, curl, resttemplate

What is the correct way to map curl -T flag if one were to use Spring resttemplate? From manpage for -T - "This transfers the specified local file to the remote URL"

This is a related curl format:-

```
curl -X PUT -T /tmp/sampleFileToUpload -v 'http://testHost/URI'
```

This is what I have - does not seem to be working though

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
map.add("file",new FileSystemResource(new File("/tmp/sampleFileToUpload")));
```

I have set content-type to multipart/form-data in the headers and then invoke exchange method. The destination gets written to - but not with the expected contents - but rather with the request parameters. From what I have read - curl -F option is straightforward to map to - example "file" as key in the map but I am not sure as to how to map -T while using resttemplate.

Here is an example: this google API - https://developers.google.com/business-communications/rcs-business-messaging/guides/build/messages/send#file_binary_example
requires --upload-file or -T option. setting content-type to multipart/form-data won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:-

```
httpHeaders.add("content-type","multipart/form-data");
...
...
httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(fileContentsAsString, httpHeaders)
```